# Rails - params form value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Hello everybody I'm looking for some help with my rails app :

I don't know why my User isn't created even i have params with value from my simple_form_for, below my controller :

```
  def create
    if current_user == nil
      @user = User.create(
        phone: params[:temp_phone],
        email: params[:temp_email]
        first_name: params[:temp_first_name],
        password: "test123456"
        )
      if @user.save
        @watch = Watch.new(watch_params)
        @watch.user = User.last
      else
        puts "#{@user.errors.messages}"
      end
    else
      @watch = Watch.new(watch_params)
      @watch.user = current_user
    end
  end
```

My view looks like this

```
    <%= simple_form_for @watch do |f| %>
      #DoSomething
    <% if current_user == nil %>
      <%= f.input :temp_first_name, label: "Name" %>
      <%= f.input :temp_email, label: "Email" %>
      <%= f.input :temp_phone, label: "Phone" %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="home-top-btn">
      <%= f.button :submit, "Estimer votre montre", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

Error is : `email can't be blank`

Basically my goal is if current_user create watch with current_user info
Else create user with params from simple_form_for then create watch

I'm pretty sure that is not the best way to go so feel free to adjust me.

Thank in advance for your help

Comment: Why do you think they are not passed? Try printing `params` at the start of the method. Or, better yet, just look at your request log in the terminal, the params should already be printed there, as part of standard rails logging.

Comment: Hello @SergioTulentsev thanks for your answer, to be honest my question was wrong.

I can see my ```params``` but i couldn't understand why **my user isn't created with this params**.

It always say ```email can't be blank``` but in params i have ```:temp_email with``` correct value

Comment: "but in params i have :temp_email with correct value" - no, you don't. As hinted at in my comment and demonstrated in the answer below, it's `params[:watch][:temp_email_with]`, not `params[:temp_email_with]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit a form you can check the parameter structure in rails server log that running on your terminal.
It will look like this.

```rb
{ watch: {
    temp_email: "something@localhost.com"
    ...other details
  }
}
```

Mind that `watch` key in params and then sub hash of other params like `temp_email` and other keys/fields.
Here what this might fix your issue.
Try to replace following code in your `create` action.

```rb
@user = User.create(
          phone: params[:watch][:temp_phone],
          email: params[:watch][:temp_email]
          first_name: params[:watch][:temp_first_name],
          password: "test123456"
        )
```

Note: This will work only if you really have a something in `@watch` instance variable.

Comment: Thank you so much for you explanation. Now i understand and my form is working perfectly

Comment: Thanks, happy to help.